# Automatic layout scope and scale

Tags: qgis, layouts

I have only one shapefile with multiple polygons. Every week I make updates to this shapefile, including new polygons, changing the shape of others and deleting other polygons, that is, this shapefile is always changing.
When preparing a layout for this shapefile, I define a geographic scope that fits all polygons and also define a scale.

As this shapefile changes frequently, I have to go back layout and again adjust the geographic scope and scale again, with each change I have to revise the layout.

How could I do it in QGIS so that the scope and scale is updated automatically, as the shapefile has changes?

Comment: Have you tried to show only that layer and use the Zoom Extents button? This should be a standard button in the toolbar.

Comment: Yes, I use Zoom Extents button every time to solve the situation. What i would like to know, if is possible updated automatically, without use Zoom Extents button. I think somethink like compare box boundary of the shp with the box of the layout e then, calculate the geographic scope and the scale, is it possible?

Comment: You could write an expression for this. It will require some math to calculate the correct scale for the height and width of your map item. You can use `layer_property( 'layername', 'extent')` to get the extent of the layer, as a geometry object. Other functions and variables that may be useful: `bounds_width(geom)`, `bounds_height(geom)`, `map_extent_width`, `map_extent_height`. You'll probably still have to click the "Update preview" button in order to see the changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/156233)